# How to Create data and return it with an association in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

First, sorry about the bad english, non native speaker. In Sequelize i have created a CRUD without any problems great ORM tool, still i would like to create and return a specific data with an association.

```
async create(req, res){
    const {minRoll,maxRoll,typeName} = req.body;

    const actionType = await ActionType.findOne({
        where: {name: typeName}
    });

    if(!actionType){
        return res.json({result:false});
    }

    const {id} = actionType;
    
    const action = await Action.create({
         minRoll: minRoll,
         maxRoll: maxRoll,
         type_id: id
    });

    return res.json(action);

},
```

How to create and return **action** with an **association**?
This is my return in Postman at the moment:

```
"id": 61,
"minRoll": 1,
"maxRoll": 3,
"type_id": 20
```

Comment: Show association definitions please

Comment: In general you need to use `include` option in `findOne/findAll` methods

Comment: @Anatoly in **findOne/findAll** it works, no problem in that one, i want to return in the **Action.create** the **association**.